# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys' in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I am getting error: **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'** in **IE8** when trying to generate a pdf report using a library jspdf.debug.js.

```
File: jspdf.debug.js, Line: 362, Column: 4
```

On this line: `var fontKey = 'F' + (Object.keys(fonts).length + 1).toString(10),`

Everything is working fine in > IE 8 versions, But I got struck in IE8.

Please help me to resolve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, [*Array.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2) does not accept any arguments, so the `10` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys Object.keys method  is only supported in IE 9 and greater.
Object.keys methods returns an array of object property names.

You might want to check your library browser compatibility. Because there may well be other obstacles.

Comment: +1, but I'm not too keen on the polyfill at MDN as it may pass a host object (e.g. a DOM element) to a native method as *this*, which may well result in an error. Given that the code will only run in browsers that are highly susceptible to the error, thought should be given to avoiding that. Similarly, *use strict* is pointless as hosts that don't support *Object.keys* are extremely unlikely to support strict mode.

Comment: RobG, could you provide a simple test case of an error when a host object is passed to a native method as this. Or if you could point to some reading. Interesting issue =)

Comment: In IE 8: `var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bottom of the *jspdf.debug.js* file you'll find a `Object.keys` polyfill amongst others. Problem is the recently added PNG support is breaking the library initialization under older browsers, so the polyfill code is never reached. This has been just [fixed](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/commit/4c69493) so give the new [1.0.119 version](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases/tag/v1.0.119) a try.

@RobG: These weird `.toString(10)` calls have been removed, too. thanks :)